# installing mysql 5.7.19 in Centos7, get errors like permission

Tags: mysql

I want to install mysql on same other place than /usr/local/mysql.
When running the command 'sudo bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/my.cnf --initialize --user=mysql', get following Error:

```
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.369158Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
`2017-10-10T02:21:27.717508Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT 
`value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
`option (see documentation for more details).
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.109331Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.272647Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.347131Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so 
`we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: b97c8f3c-ad61-11e7-a737-000c299b2d06.
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.351277Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.357864Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: Pl)v)1&Zhl+D
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.369007Z 1 [ERROR] 1  Can't create/write to file '/home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/data/mysql/db.MYI' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
`2017-10-10T02:21:29.369158Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

`2017-10-10T02:21:29.496351Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open '/home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/data/ib_buffer_pool.incomplete' for writing: Permission denied`
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=/home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64
datadir=/home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/data
port=3307
character-set-server=utf8
server_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running the mysql daemon as the mysql user (`--user=mysql`). However, you are giving it a path that exists in the hadoop user's home directory. The mysql user doesn't have access to the hadoop home directory.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` user should have, `read, write, execute` permission

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/
```

**OR**

If you want directory to be used by 2 user then use [`setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)

```
setfacl -R -m u:mysql:rwx -m u:some_other_user:rw /home/hadoop/app/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/
```

if you want to give permission to specific group then instead of `:u` use `:g`